# Can't install therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried different Rubies and still can't install this gem. Ubuntu 16.10

```
duke@ostrov:~$ gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/duke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161220-631-1qvqd0t.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling v8_locker.cpp
v8_locker.cpp: In function ‘VALUE {anonymous}::Lock::Delete(VALUE)’:
v8_locker.cpp:45:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
v8_locker.cpp: In function ‘VALUE {anonymous}::Unlock::Delete(VALUE)’:
v8_locker.cpp:85:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
compiling v8_weakref.cpp
compiling v8_value.cpp
v8_value.cpp:100:9: warning: ‘VALUE {anonymous}::ToInt32(VALUE)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   VALUE ToInt32(VALUE self) {
         ^~~~~~~
compiling v8_script.cpp
compiling v8_array.cpp
compiling v8_handle.cpp
compiling v8_try_catch.cpp
v8_try_catch.cpp: In function ‘v8::TryCatch* {anonymous}::unwrap(VALUE)’:
v8_try_catch.cpp:15:14: error: cannot convert ‘bool’ to ‘v8::TryCatch*’ in return
       return false;
              ^~~~~
Makefile:216: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «v8_try_catch.o»
make: *** [v8_try_catch.o] Ошибка 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/duke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/duke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/therubyracer-0.10.2/gem_make.out
```

I tried some other answers on related questions but nothing helps me. I am out of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This package contains the header files needed for extension libraries for Ruby 1.9.1. You need to install the ruby1.9.1-dev package by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Generally it's easier to just do:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Comment: you can do one thing purge ruby first and then install it. Don't forget to remove Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is `libv8`, so you should uninstall `libv8` via command as bellow:

```
gem uninstall libv8
```

Then run `gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'` again. It will work.